# How to find the point of intersection of four parametric equations

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to find the TWO points of intersection of the parametric equations:

$x = \cos t, y = \sin t$ and $x = 2+4 \cos s, y = 3+4 \sin s$.

Would I set $\cos t = 2+4 \cos s$ and $\sin t = 3+4 \sin s$? How would I solve it afterwards?

Comment: Generally, setting these equations equal should give you where they intersect. You would also presumably have to define a period which this solution would be valid.

Comment: @franklin: I would assume the period would  be $2\pi$. Is that correct?

Comment: Hint: Recalling the identity $\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)=1$ should also be useful.  This would allow you to reduce your problem to a single equation in a single variable.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could see the first parametric equation as:

$$x^2+y^2=1$$

And the second one as:

$$(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2=16$$

Comment: I ended up having: $(\frac{2-6\sqrt{3}}{13}, \frac{3+4\sqrt{3}}{13})$ and $(\frac{2+6\sqrt{3}}{13}, \frac{3-4\sqrt{3}}{13})$.

Comment: @MathyPerson see this http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427ek25i07ttuq

Answer (score 0):

The first curve is a circle with centre in the origin and radius $1$. The second curve is a circle with centre in the point $(2,3)$ and radius $4$. The intersection points can be found by solving:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl} x^2+y^2&=& 1\\ (x-2)^2+(y-3)^2 &=& 16.\end{array}\right. $$

Comment: I ended up having: $(\frac{2-6\sqrt{3}}{13}, \frac{3+4\sqrt{3}}{13})$ and $(\frac{2+6\sqrt{3}}{13}, \frac{3-4\sqrt{3}}{13})$.

Answer (score 0):

I would parameterize the 4 parametric equations.

Therefore, for the first pair we have:

$$\sin^2t + \cos^2t = 1,\ x^2 + y^2 = 1$$

And for the second pair we have:

$$\cos s = \frac{x-2}{4}$$

and $$\sin s = \frac{y-3}{4}$$

Therefore we get that:

$$\sin^2s + \cos^2s = 1,\ \left(\frac{x-2}{4}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y-3}{4}\right)^2 = 1$$

Then you set the two equations equal to one another to find the point of intersection.